# What's this bolt head type and how can I open it?

Tags: screws, bolts, screwdriver

There is a bolt screwed inside a long hole:

[image: Bolt]

I don't know the bolt head type. Is there a trick to open it?

Comment: For completeness, in what kind of situation/item is this bolt located ?

Comment: @Criggie Well, it's for a coffee maker device I'm trying to crack open due to this: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/104383/80108

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is this kind of security bolt head called, and how can I remove it?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/18766/what-is-this-kind-of-security-bolt-head-called-and-how-can-i-remove-it)

Comment: @shoover It does, except the fact that my bolt is inside a long hole =)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like a spanner tamper-proof security bolt. Either buy a set of tamper-proof security bits, or modify a cheap standard slotted screwdriver with a dremel tool. Here is a cheap set: [https://www.amazon.com/Performance-Tool-W8659-Security-32-Piece/dp/B002KS19PK/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B002KS19PK) A good chance that something in this set will work, but no guarantee.

Comment: This set has 4 different security slotted bits. I've never run into one that this set couldn't open.

https://www.amazon.com/Neiko-10048A-Security-Vanadium-100-Piece/dp/B000O5XDOG

Answer (score 10):

It is a simple security slot headed screw.

A flat headed screw has part of the slot filled in to make it difficult for the average joe to undo.

Either purchase a set of security bits or take an old screwdriver and grind out the matching part on the screwdriver blade so it fits neatly.

Comment: It's trivial to make it from a normal flat screwdriver with a hacksaw. The crappier the screwdriver the better. Higher-quality ones tend to have really hard blades that crack and chip away when you try to cut into them this way.

Answer (score 5):

I recently found out the local name for a head like that translates to slotted flat. The screwdriver fitting those heads is an H-screwdriver. Look like this:

[image: H-screwdrivers]

However, for the smaller screws (with heads up to 5-6mm), it's common to simply take an old flathead screwdriver and a hacksaw. Might take a couple of minutes, but they can be made yourself quite easily. The bigger the pin in the middle of the bolthead, the more work you have with the hacksaw. On the really big ones, pliers could work but I wouldn't recommend it.

I don't see those boltheads as often as I used to (say 10-15 years ago), I think manufacturers prefer Torx nowadays in places where I used to see slotted flats.

Answer (score 4):

That is a style of head, known of as "notched spanner", most security bit sets will have bits to fit it. The bit is like a normal flatblade screwdriver but with a notch cut in the middle.

Unfortunately bits generally don't work on screws that are down holes, because the bit (or worse for deep holes or short bits, the combination of bit and bit holder) ends up with a diameter too large to fit down the hole. I have never seen a regular screwdriver for sale with this type of head.

I suspect buying a cheap flatblade screwdriver and modifying it is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `long hole` issue =)